# p:commandButton update - alters "viewpoint" on page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Sort of an odd question and I'd like to NOT give away code if possible, so I'll do my best to explain what is going on.

Basically, I have a commandButton that performs an AJAX action and then updates the entire form that it is inside of.

This form works like such:

```
<h:form id="tabform">

    .....

    <p:commandButton update=":tabform" value="Save" ajax="true" onstart="savingDialog.show();" onsuccess="savingDialog.hide();" actionListener="#{bean.saveContent}" /> <!-- styling makes it fixed position -->


    .....

    <p:editor id="ed1" />
    <p:editor id="ed2" />
    <p:editor id="ed3" />
    <p:editor id="ed4" />
    <p:editor id="ed5" />
    <p:editor id="ed6" />


</h:form>
```

When I click the save button, and I am at like editor 5, it will save and then place me in the middle of editor 2. Not focus, but "focus of the browser view" (if that makes sense).

I can confirm it has everything to do with the update on the commandButton. It appears to put me half way in the middle of the tabform after the update.

Is there ANY way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scrollTo` method on the  [`RequestContext`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf) to scroll to a specific component after any server side action. Obviously this will require you devise a scheme to know beforehand, the component you want to level the page to. Without meaningful code from you, you can start off with the following:

```
public void saveContent(){
   //your implementation here
   RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
   context.scrollTo("tabForm:ed5")  

}
```

Comment: It wasn't quite what I was looking for (based on my current design), but I was able to use this answer to help me figure out a way to pull the current scroll on push, then reassign the window scroll on complete.